# ExUnit triggers Empty Error with setup_all block

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

I have a test which requires preinserted data.

So I am trying to setup those data with `setup_all` callback as those data can be setup once.

Since I do not want to assign anything to context, I defined `setup_all` like below

```
setup_all do
  create_languages() 
  create_regions()
  create_currencies() 
  create_user()
  :ok
end
```

And each test has a function, which gets one struct from data created.

For example, one of tests is like below:

```
test "update_core/2 (region_id) with valid data, updates core" do
  region = get_region()
  core = create_core()

  {:ok, core} = Cores.update_core(core, %{region_id: region.id})

  assert region.id == core.region_id
end
```

However, `region = get_region()` triggers an empty error. Why can this function get struct? `IO.inspect` shows `create_regions()` actually create multiple regions. Am I missing something here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good chance that Ecto has either been configured to be used in sandbox mode or set to reset the database after every test, in your `:test` environment. So you should use `setup` block instead of `setup_all`:

```
setup do
  create_languages() 
  create_regions()
  create_currencies() 
  create_user()
  :ok
end
```

The `setup` block is called before every test, while `setup_all` is only called once.

Comment: The reason why I want to use `setup_all` rather than `setup` is that since `setup` calls for each individual test so it takes long time to do...

Comment: Yes, but that's the proper way to go, so different tests don't interfere with each other. To speed up tests, you can make sure that Ecto is indeed set up in Sandbox mode, and [run them concurrently](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.html) by setting the `async` tag to true.